# How do I implement Facebook auto-login on Android (Facebook SDK 4.0.0)?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm using Android Studio and Facebook SDK 4.0.0. Currently I'm able to successfully login. However, when I restart the app I have to sign in again. How can I implement auto-login so that the app automatically connects with my Facebook account when I start it? I've tried the 'Session' class but it won't work since it has been replaced by 'LoginManager'.

Answer (score 0):

As per the facebook developers' site:

> The Android and iOS SDKs don't currently support re-authentication.

Visit following link to know details:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication

Answer (score 0):

first get username id using sharedPreference  like this:

```
private  SharedPreferences settings ;
    private void graphRequest(AccessToken accessToken) {
        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse   
                response) {
                    try {
                        String email = "";
                        if (object.has("email")) {
                            email = object.getString("email");
                        }
                        String id = object.getString("id");
                        String name = object.getString("name");
                        String gender = object.getString("gender");

                        editor.putString("username", id);
                        editor.putString("name", name);
                        editor.putString("gender", gender);
                        editor.putString("email", email);
                        editor.apply();

                        startActivity(new Intent(mContext, 
                        MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
         Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
         parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender");
         request.setParameters(parameters);
         request.executeAsync();
     }
```

Check condition OnResume() like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    settings =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(settings.getString("username", ""))) {
        startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
      }
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    super.onResume();
}
```